# Saving and converting attached Outlook file with VBA

Tags: xml, vba, outlook, xlsx

I have this code for saving the attached file from emails to a given folder. But I would like to convert these files before saving as well. Especially the xml files to xlsx.

Could anybody help me?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
       Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
       Dim saveFolder As String
       Dim dateFormat As String

       dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
       saveFolder = "C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\xml\"
       For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xml") Then
             objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          End If

          Set objAtt = Nothing
       Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You'd probably need to open them in Excel first - then do a SaveAs. You could get some sample code to start with by recording a macro that does this

Comment: Are you running this code from Excel or from Outlook? Looks like it might be Excel, since you've fully-qualified the `itm as Outlook.MailItem`, in which case opening/saving the file will be slightly easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.

```
Public Sub saveconvAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat As String
Dim convFormat As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

saveFolder = "C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\xml\"
convFolder = "C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\xls\"
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH-mm-ss")

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(saveFolder)
    If UCase(Right(objAtt.FileName, Len(XML))) = UCase(XML) Then
        NewFileName = convFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName & "_conv.xlsx"

Set ConvertThis = Workbooks.Open(saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName)
        ConvertThis.SaveAs FileName:=NewFileName, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ConvertThis.Close
    End If
Next
Set objAtt = Nothing
```

End Sub